# Classify individuals according to their object properties with certain rules in Protege

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

I have an example ontology in Protege 5.5 (I added it below). With this ontology I need to classify individuals according to their object properties. My rules are like these;

> if an individual A (`subClassOf: A`) has exact 1 object property (`hasRelation`) with B (`subClassOf: B`) OR individual B (`subClassOf: B`) has exact 1 object property (`hasRelation`) with A (`subClassOf: A`) then it is `subClassOf: OneToOne`.

> if an individual A (`subClassOf: A`) has min 2 object properties (`hasRelation`) with B (`subClassOf: B`) then it is `subClassOf: ManyToOne`.

> if an individual B (`subClassOf: B`) has min 2 object properties (`hasRelation`) with A (`subClassOf: A`) then it is `subClassOf: OneToMany`.

> if an individual A (`subClassOf: A`) has min 2 object properties (`hasRelation`) with A (`subClassOf: A`) AND B (`subClassOf: B`) has min 2 object properties (`hasRelation`) with A (`subClassOf: A`) then it is `subClassOf: ManyToMany`.

I think maybe this can be done with SWRL but I couldn't make it work.

Any idea appreciated.

```
Prefix: : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/example#>
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>



Ontology: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/example>


ObjectProperty: hasRelation

    Characteristics: 
        Symmetric
    
    
Class: A

    SubClassOf: 
        Data
    
    
Class: B

    SubClassOf: 
        Data
    
    
Class: Data

    
Class: ManyToMany

    SubClassOf: 
        RelationType
    
    
Class: ManyToOne

    SubClassOf: 
        RelationType
    
    
Class: OneToMany

    SubClassOf: 
        RelationType
    
    
Class: OneToOne

    SubClassOf: 
        RelationType
    
    
Class: RelationType

    
Individual: A1

    Facts:  
     hasRelation  B1
    
    
Individual: A2

    Facts:  
     hasRelation  B2
    
    
Individual: A3

    Facts:  
     hasRelation  B2
    
    
Individual: A4

    Facts:  
     hasRelation  B3,
     hasRelation  B4
    
    
Individual: B1

    
Individual: B2

    
Individual: B3

    
Individual: B4

    
DisjointClasses: 
    ManyToMany,ManyToOne,OneToMany,OneToOne
```